# How to print something at a specific time of the day

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

Is it possible to have python 2.7 print something at a specific time of the day. For example if I ran the program at 15:06 and coded it to print "Do task now" at 15:07 it prints it. So no matter what time you ran the program once it hit 15:07 it would print "Do task now." In addition is it possible to have it print every week at this time?

Comment: Yes python can do that.

Comment: Thank you @StephenRauch but how would I code this?

Comment: I would suggest investigating the datetime module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: I wouldn't use python to schedule the operation. Your operating system already has tools to run any application at a specific time

Comment: @cricket_007 there could be good reasons the user needs this, we just don't know and we can't assume that it's for scheduling tasks.

Comment: @Ryan will you be expecting it in a specific timezone, or will the timezone be local to the machine it's running on?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Comment: Thank you for your response @Vincenzzzochi no it will be local to the machine it is running on

Comment: @Ryan you're welcome. Also, when do we decide that "it is currently before 15:07", meaning if we ran this at 1am today, would this be before or after 15:07? Is the cutoff midnight? By every week in your question, you mean maybe one specific day a week?

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi Yeah so if the time was Saturday at 15:07, it would print it, once a week at that time.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest installing the library schedule, if you're able to.

Use `pip install schedule`

Your code would look like this if utilizing schedule:

```
import schedule
import time

def task():
    print("Do task now")

schedule.every().day.at("15:07").do(task)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

You can adjust `time.sleep(1)` as necessary to sleep for longer if a 1s interval is too long. Here is the [schedule library page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule).

Answer (score 1):

While python is not ideal to schedule something; there are better tools out there. Yet, if this is desired to be done in **python** below is a way to implement it:

**Prints at *`scheduled_time`* of 11AM:**

```
import datetime as dt
scheduled_time = dt.time(11,00,00,0)
while 1==1:
    if (scheduled_time < dt.datetime.now().time() and 
       scheduled_time > (dt.datetime.now()- dt.timedelta(seconds=59)).time() ):
        print "Now is the time to print"
        break
```

> There are two `if conditions` with an intent to print within one minute; a shorter duration can be chosen. But the `break` immediately after `print` ensures that `print` is executed only once.

You would need to extrapolate this so that code is run across days.

Refer: [*`datetime`* Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using `cron`, then the general solution is to find the time remaining until you need the event to occur, have the program sleep for that duration, then continue execution.

The tricky part is to have the program find the next occurrence of a given time. There are some modules for this, but you could also do it with plain code for a well-defined case where it is only a fixed time of day.

```
import time

target_time = '15:07:00'
current_epoch = time.time()

# get string of full time and split it
time_parts = time.ctime().split(' ')
# replace the time component to your target
time_parts[3] = target_time
# convert to epoch
future_time = time.mktime(time.strptime(' '.join(time_parts)))

# if not in the future, add a day to make it tomorrow
diff = future_time - current_epoch
if diff < 0:
    diff += 86400

time.sleep(diff)
print 'Done waiting, lets get to work'
```